# ¿Cómo resolver HSC_HUGE_SHARED_STRING_CONSTANT?

Tags: java, string

Hola tengo una clase con una cadena constante mega enorme

```
public class CharsetXYZ extends Charset {
    private static class Decoder extends XYZDecoder {
        private static final String INDEX= "HUGE STRING CONSTANT 1234567890abcchdefghijklllmnñopqrstuvwxyz...";
        ...
    }
}
```

y findbugs me reporta el error:

> INDEX is initialized to a string constant 7213 characters long that is duplicated in 6 other class files
>
> HSC_HUGE_SHARED_STRING_CONSTANT: Huge string constants is duplicated across multiple class files

[Los dos atajos de Oracle](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6447475) no se me hacen las ideales que son:

quitar la palabra reservada `final`.

```
public class CharsetXYZ extends Charset {
    private static class Decoder extends XYZDecoder {
        private static String INDEX= "HUGE STRING CONSTANT 1234567890abcchdefghijklllmnñopqrstuvwxyz...";
        ...
    }
}
```

envolver la constante en un bloque de inicialización estático.

```
public class CharsetXYZ extends Charset {
 private final static String INDEX;
 static {
    INDEX = "HUGE STRING CONSTNT2"
 }
}
```

¿Alguna otra forma que tengan de solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué versión del JDK estás usando? Yo acabo de hacer una prueba con la versión 1.8.0_172 del OracleJDK y no tengo el problema que describe ese BUG, que al parecer está resuelto desde la versión 1.6. NOTA: No he probado con Sonar.

Comment: @E.Betanzos 1.8.0_201 y findbugs 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que no hay otra forma de solucionarlo.

La variante que considero más recomendable es inicializar la constante dentro de un bloque `static{...}` ya que de este modo no tienes que quitar la palabra `final` y evitas que te modifiquen el valor de la variable `INDEX`.

Realicé pruebas tanto con el OracleJDK 1.8.0_172 como con el OpenJDK 11.0.2 y en ambos casos se duplica la constante en cada archivo .class si no utilizo el bloque `static{...}`.

Comment: y al duplicarse la constante aumenta el tamaño del .class no?

Comment: Claro, ese es el problema que se evita con esta solución. Literalmente lo que muestra el bytecode es que en cada clase donde uses la referencia a dicha constante habrá  una copia.